# Facebook Login URL Blocked Issue

Tags: php, facebook

I need to integrate Facebook login into my site
I have used some library to do this and then I provided the following URL in Valid OAuth:

```
  Redirect URIs: My valid OAuth Url was :
        https:/mydomain.com/smedia_test/index.php/hauth/endpoint?hauth_done=Facebook.

        I have set below details in Facebook app
        Facebook App Details :

        Basic Setting :

        App Domains : mydomain.com

        Site URL : https://example.com/smedia_test/index.php/

        Advance setting :

        Server IP Whitelist : My Ipaddress

        Facebook login Setting:

        Valid OAuth Redirect URIs
        https:/example.com/smedia_test/index.php/hauth/endpoint?hauth_done=Facebook
```

However, I got the error message "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.".
 How can I fix this? And also Facebook login is not working in localhost

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to make your URL to be exactly the same as the URL you provide to the **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** setting. For example, if you are getting the Facebook login URL like this

```
    $login_fb_url = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);
```

Make sure that the same URL `https://www.example.com/fb-callback.php` is used in the **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** setting of your application.